# Develop on windows, run unicorn in production on heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails, git, heroku, bundler

I have a new Rails project and i decided to give heroku a try, deployment seems very easy there

I am developing on windows, so running unicorn is not a choice, but webrick is fine for development

BUT, when it come to deployment , i want to use unicorn, and heroku perfectly support this

The Problem Is: i have to list unicorn on my Gemfile in order for heroku to pick it, but when i do that and run bundle command (or rails s) on my windows dev machine, it tries to install the unicorn server

i tried to put unicorn in the production group,
    group :production do
      gem 'unicorn'
    end
still bundle complain and i cannot run the dev server

Answer (score 42, accepted):

You can target specific platforms in your Gemfile:

```
platforms :ruby do # linux
  gem 'unicorn'
end

platforms :mswin do
  # gems specific to windows
end
```

see the [manpages for gemfile](http://gembundler.com/man/gemfile.5.html) for more information.

Answer (score 16):

The alternative solution (which the original poster was very close to) is

```
group :production do
  gem 'unicorn'
end
```

and then using

```
bundle install --without production
```

on your Windows machine.

**Heroku sidenote** (not tested)

Unlike the accepted answer, this should not cause Heroku to ignore your `Gemfile.lock`

This is because Heroku checks your Gemfile for `mswin` and `mingw` when deciding if it is Windows generated or not.

Comment: Windows 7: `gem 'unicorn', group: :production` gives me an error with installing `kgio`while  `gem 'unicorn', platforms: :ruby` does not.