# Can't bundle/install Kgio Error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, installation, bundle

I can't seem to install kgio with my app, every time I do bundle install. I get this error ! Can anyone help me? I have tried re bundling like 5 times already.

```
C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
    checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... no
    checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC() in time.h... no
    checking for clockid_t in time.h... no
    checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
    checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
    checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
    checking for poll() in poll.h... no
    checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
    getaddrinfo required
    *** extconf.rb failed ***
    Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
    necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
    details.  You may need configuration options.

    Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/RailsInstaller/Ruby1.9.3/bin/ruby
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
```

Comment: You can just skip kgio on Windows then, see this answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764199/develop-on-windows-run-unicorn-in-production-on-heroku

Answer (score 26):

Actually, the answer is that you can't use kgio with windows. I spent 3 hours sweating through the other answer here before finding that out. Kgio needs a unix-like environment according to it's developer.

Comment: Yes Ya, you are absolutely right, I moved to Linux at work for the same reason. Good luck !

Answer (score 9):

You are probably missing required libraries.

Also from [RubyInstaller Wiki](https://github.com/oneclick/rubyinstaller/wiki/Troubleshooting#wiki-devkit_dll_conflict)

This failure is due to the native gem compile/install process using a version of libiconv-2.dll other than the one integrated into the DevKit due to how Windows searches for DLLs

This can be worked around by searching your computer for the file libiconv-2.dll and renaming, deleting, or otherwise moving any found instances out of the way and re-running the native gem install process or in your case Bundle Install

It is recommended that if you don’t know why or what put the libiconv-2.dll file in the directory in which you found it, that you move it back after you compile whatever gems you need. This will possibly prevent other applications from breaking.

**EDIT**:

The kgio gem only builds and runs on Unix like systems (http://bogomips.org/kgio/)  It uses functions which are not natively available on Windows.

If you are trying to use Unicorn, then you just need to replace the webserver.

Give Thin a try. Add the following lines to your Gemfile:

```
gem 'thin'
```

Comment: It doesn't let me do 'bundle install' because it says you need to have mentioned .dll fine. Please Help !