# gem install kgio ERROR

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rubygems, bundle

I've downloaded a rails open source webapp , and while i was starting it using :

```
C:\Users\admin\Downloads\iCare\icare-develop>rails server
←[31mCould not find kgio-2.8.0 in any of the sources←[0m
←[33mRun `bundle install` to install missing gems.←[0m
```

i tried to fix this error using:

```
cmd:>gem install kgio -v '2.8.0'
```

i got the error:

```
Temporarily enhancing PATH to include DevKit...
Building native extensions.  This could take a while...
ERROR:  Error installing kgio:
ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby.exe extconf.rb
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC in time.h... no
checking for CLOCK_MONOTONIC() in time.h... no
checking for clockid_t in time.h... no
checking for clock_gettime() in -lrt... no
checking for t_open() in -lnsl... no
checking for socket() in -lsocket... no
checking for poll() in poll.h... no
checking for getaddrinfo() in sys/types.h,sys/socket.h,netdb.h... no
getaddrinfo required
*** extconf.rb failed ***
Could not create Makefile due to some reason, probably lack of
necessary libraries and/or headers.  Check the mkmf.log file for more
details.  You may need configuration options.
```

and

```
Provided configuration options:
        --with-opt-dir
        --without-opt-dir
        --with-opt-include
        --without-opt-include=${opt-dir}/include
        --with-opt-lib
        --without-opt-lib=${opt-dir}/lib
        --with-make-prog
        --without-make-prog
        --srcdir=.
        --curdir
        --ruby=C:/Ruby193/bin/ruby
        --with-rtlib
        --without-rtlib
        --with-nsllib
        --without-nsllib
        --with-socketlib
        --without-socketlib
```

and
    Gem files will remain installed in C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.8.
    0 for inspection.
    Results logged to C:/Ruby193/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/kgio-2.8.0/ext/kgio/gem_ma
    ke.out

i did type:`bundle install` after, but nothing happened..

Comment: i added those 'and' between the codes sections because i couldn't submit my question

Answer (score 14, accepted):

kgio is only for *nix system.

the kgio gem page:

> kgio 2.8.0 kgio provides non-blocking I/O methods for Ruby without
>   raising exceptions on EAGAIN and EINPROGRESS. It is intended for use
>   with the Unicorn and Rainbows! Rack servers, but may be used by other
>   applications (**that run on Unix-like platforms**).

Comment: u're right; i tried it on ubuntu virtually installed, and it works !

Comment: so we know its for unix-like platforms... how does that help us?  if i don't want to virtually install ubunto, how can i get it so this gem doesn't install/isn't required?

Comment: Should you need to use Unicorn (or similar) in your final application but not for development, try adding to your Gemfile:
`group :production, :test do
  gem 'unicorn'  
end`

Comment: Adding group will not be enough if you are running on a windows machine. follow the tip [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10764443/1461972), using `'platforms :ruby do # linux
  gem 'unicorn'
end

platforms :mswin do
  # gems specific to windows
end`

Answer (score 3):

Try this

```
platforms :ruby do # linux

  gem 'unicorn'

end

platforms :mswin do

  # gems specific to windows

end
```

Source:
[Develop on windows, run unicorn in production on heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10764199/develop-on-windows-run-unicorn-in-production-on-heroku)

Answer (score 0):

I think you're using windows operating system , so only thing you need to get ride of this error is to comment in or remove the **gem 'unicorn'** in you gem file as this is only for linux systems